# How do I dual boot Backtrack 5r3 on a PC with Windows 8.1?

Tags: multi-boot, windows-8.1, backtrack

I am curious about working on Backtrack but don't want to remove the Windows 8.1(64 bit) OS.Can anybody help me with the step-by-step process to dual-boot Backtrack 5R3 with Windows 8.1 ?
I have the Backtrack 5R3 32-bit ISO file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dual booting is quite the pain, and yields [virtually] zero benefits over virtual machines.

With that said, I recommend [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). It is extremely easy to setup. That way you can have hundreds of OS's with dynamic storage that is completely separate and can be used in parallel to your existing. And it makes it easy to create snapshots of a base image that you finally configured well enough to trust that you may revert back to at any time.

EDIT: I just realized you mentioned BT5, and so it would make sense why you might not want a VM for that. Alas, I still don't have a solid answer since it would be too long of an answer anyways. I suggest you run `diskmgmt.msc` and create some space for an empty partition, and then boot to the Kali/BT6 or BT5 LiveDVD and see if you can get it to work, and then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I agree that a virtual machine is better but they have one disadvantage, they don't allow you to use or enable the host's built-in Wifi adapter. And this is a setback when someone is trying to begin using Backtrack !
Btw,thnx for responding jRadd !

Comment: That is a good point. When I want to use linux for pentesting or something like that I prefer to load Kali Linux on a thumb drive using something like pendrivelinux so that I can enable monitor mode on my wlan adapter, or even just a livedvd. You can also install a persistent install of linux on the thumb drive, so that you can make changes/updates.

Comment: Now that's a good idea. I'll try out this one too. Thnx !